# Custom keyboard I created with ukalele not working

Tags: keyboard

I created a custom layout with Ukalele. This file is here: http://www.filedropper.com/koray1

The filename is: koray1.keylayout

I copied this file to /Library/Keyboard Layouts

However I do not see it available for selecting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you login/logout?  Check the Other category?  Use the same thing for the Keyboard Name?  In any case, a good place to ask for help is the Ukelele group  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes I did restart, logout login etc.. Nothing works.

Comment: But your keyboard name is not Koray.  It's Turkish qwerty pc, which duplicates one already present in the system.  Try fixing that.

Comment: @TomGewecke how do I change the name of the keyboard

Comment: Look in the Ukelele menus for an item like Set Keyboard Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keyboard Name is not set correctly.  It duplicates one already in use by the system.  Instead you should make it koray1.